# Which are the differences between hook_node_view_alter and hook_preprocess_node?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming, nodes

I have to remove some elements from a node before show it, but I can't understand where it's better to put the code. 
Mainly I can't understand the differences between [`hook_node_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) and [`hook_preprocess_node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). It seems they do the same thing as they receive a render array as parameter.

I think the best option should be to use the [`hook_node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) but it isn't the right way to do this because in this hook only `$node->content` is editable.

Comment: Yes, sure I meant hook_preprocess_node. I changed it in the question for better indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_preprocess_node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) is more generic, and thus more limited, and happens after [`hook_node_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).

Both operate on the similar array, basically, but hook_node_view_alter operates at earlier stage. So, first reason is ordering of actions, second is accessing a bit different data sets, as they changes between stages of execution. [`dpr()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpr/7) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) their arguments to see exact differences. That's all. Nothing much to it, really.

Comment: Just to note, my answer was posted [when there was](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/88933/2) `template_preprocess_node` in a question, not `hook_preprocess_node`...

Comment: Sure I'm sorry if my change was a problem for you. 
By the way, can you explain me the main difference between these two hooks? Thank you.

Comment: @LateAtNight Answer updated